# Wrong time on achievements

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

So I answered a question on SO and got an up vote. (Yay!)

When I got the up vote, the achievement in the dropdown said that I can talk in chat now (I'm not very active on SO) and +10 for the answer... but the header of the two achievements said Yesterday.

It happened the same day at the time of when I noticed this issue,  ~9:00PM EST. The question was posted 4h ago, and my answer that was upvoted was from 2h ago.

My hypotheses is that somewhere there is a bad conversion to/from GMT causing the app to think that it is 5hrs in the future.

**Edit:** Screenshot: (it was difficult to edit)

[image: Note the boxes. The time is 9:45 PM, the answer is from 3hrs ago, and the achievements says yesterday.]

Stack Exchange 1.0.73
Samsung Galaxy S II Skyrocket i727
Android 4.1.2

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it

Comment: There you go. I edited it.

Comment: SE is on UTC, so it **was** yesterday.

Comment: @EasyasPi see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, the App is working in accordance with the way SE works.

Everything on SE is based off of UTC, not local time, so that means that the SE "day" ends for you in EST at 7 PM EST.

So, if you get an upvote before 7PM EST and it's now after that time, the achievements are correct in saying that you received the upvote "yesterday".

Your upvote was logged at 21:50 UTC on September 10th but it's now September 11th UTC.

[image: Upvote Log]

As a caveat, you will notice that the question and answer dates are based on a 24-hour timeline from when they are posted, not based on the UTC... so a question won't say "asked yesterday" until 24 hours have passed. Up until then, it will say "asked [hours] hour[s] ago".

[image: Asked hours ago]

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification! Although it is still a bit quirky if I say so myself. But consistency >= accuracy